# Logs no postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Bom dia Pessoal, tenho uma `trigger` para logar `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE` no `postgresql`, porém o jeito que estou logando, é como se o usuário do próprio banco tivesse feito a operação. Eu precisava que fosse salvo o usuário do sistema que as modificou.

Criação de um schema para a tabela
`CREATE SCHEMA logging;`

Criação da tabela

```
CREATE TABLE logging.logs (
        id              serial,
        data            timestamp without timezone DEFAULT now(),
        schema          text,
        tabela          text,
        operacao        text,
        usuario         text DEFAULT current_user <--- pegando o usuário do banco,
        valor_novo      json,
        valor_antigo    json
);
```

Criação da função

```
CREATE FUNCTION change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
       BEGIN
         IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
         THEN INSERT INTO logging.logs (
                tabela, schema, operacao, valor_novo
              ) VALUES (
                TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW)
              );
           RETURN NEW;
         ELSIF  TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
         THEN INSERT INTO logging.logs (
             tabela, schema, operacao, valor_novo, valor_antigo
           )
           VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
           RETURN NEW;
         ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
         THEN INSERT INTO logging.logs
             (tabela, schema, operacao, valor_antigo)
             VALUES (
               TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD)
             );
             RETURN OLD;
         END IF;
       END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Criando a trigger na tabela desejada

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tabela_exemplo
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_trigger();
```

A tabela de usuário esta no schema app, ou seja, eu a acesso assim -> `app.users`.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Se você não deseja o `current_user` do banco então modifique seus comandos `INSERT` e inclua `usuario` na lista de campos e o valor do usuário do sistema que deseja colocar na tabela.